# php multidimensional array grouping

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array which contains clothing `Attributes` and `Variations`, each Attribute has an unknown quantity of Variations.

The array I have is this ...

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Variation' => array(
        'title' => '40 inch'
    ),
    'Attribute' => array(
        'title' => 'Size'
    )
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'Variation' => array(
        'title' => '42 inch'
    ),
    'Attribute' => array(
        'title' => 'Size'
    )
),
(int) 2 => array(
    'Variation' => array(
        'title' => 'Long'
    ),
    'Attribute' => array(
        'title' => 'Length'
    )
),
(int) 3 => array(
    'Variation' => array(
        'title' => 'Short'
    ),
    'Attribute' => array(
        'title' => 'Length'
    )
)
)
```

and I'm trying to group and re-order it to give this

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Attribute' => array(
        'title' => 'Size',
    ),
    'Variation' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'title' => '40 inch',
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'title' => '42 inch',
        )
    )
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'Attribute' => array(
        'title' => 'Length',
    ),
    'Variation' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'title' => 'Short',
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'title' => 'Long',
        )
    )
),
)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

I managed to solve it quite simply like this

```
$res=[];

foreach($test as $row){
    $res[$row['Attribute']['title']][]=$row['Variation']['title'];
}
```

which gave me this

```
array(
'Size' => array(
    (int) 0 => '40 inch',
    (int) 1 => '42 inch',
),
'Length' => array(
    (int) 0 => 'Long',
    (int) 1 => 'Short',
),
)
```

and thats something I can work with.
Thanks for everyone's input.
I upvoted all answers, but as Im just a newbie here it doesnt publicly show.

Comment: you have not mention what you have tried and where facing error.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers, I actually solved it like this 
$res=[];

foreach($test as $row){
 $res[$row['Attribute']['title']][]=$row['Variation']['title'];
}

Answer (score 0):

Though the `index`s for main array will be different, his can help -

```
$new= array();

foreach($var as $arr) {

    $new[$arr['Attribute']['title']]['Attribute']['title'] = $arr['Attribute']['title'];
    $new[$arr['Attribute']['title']]['Variation'][] = array('title' => $arr['Variation']['title']); 

}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/528594)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$old = array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Variation' => array(
            'title' => '40 inch'
        ),
        'Attribute' => array(
            'title' => 'Size'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Variation' => array(
            'title' => '42 inch'
        ),
        'Attribute' => array(
            'title' => 'Size'
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'Variation' => array(
            'title' => 'Long'
        ),
        'Attribute' => array(
            'title' => 'Length'
        )
    ),
    (int) 3 => array(
        'Variation' => array(
            'title' => 'Short'
        ),
        'Attribute' => array(
            'title' => 'Length'
        )
    )
);
$new = array();
$attr = '';
$i = -1;
foreach ($old as $arr) {
    if($attr != $arr['Attribute']['title']){
        $attr = $arr['Attribute']['title'];
        $i++;
    }
    $new[$i]['Attribute']['title'] = $arr['Attribute']['title'];
    $new[$i]['Variation'][] = array('title' => $arr['Variation']['title']);
}
print_r($new);
?>
```

output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Attribute] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Size
                )

            [Variation] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => 40 inch
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => 42 inch
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Attribute] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Length
                )

            [Variation] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Long
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Short
                        )

                )

        )

)
```